# async.series function unable to access member of container class

Tags: node.js, async.js

I have used `async.series` within a member function of a class but unable to access this reference and thus the members of that class from within the `async.series` functions - any workaround for this?

How can I declare `async series` pattern within a class and access the class members within the `async series`  pattern ?

```
async = require("async");
class X {
  constructor() {
    this.member = 1;     /*< --- member declaration*/
  }
  f(){
    async.series([      /*< --- async declaration*/
      function (cb) {
        console.log('s1')
        cb();
      },
      function (cb) {
        console.log('s2')
        console.log(this.member)      /*< --- member access failing here*/
        cb();
      }
    ], function(){
      console.log('here')
    });
  }
}

(new X()).f()
```

Following is the output:

```
s1
s2
TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of undefined
    at /home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/index.js:14:26
    at /home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2948:28
    at replenish (/home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:440:21)
    at /home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:445:13
    at eachOfLimit$1 (/home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:471:34)
    at awaitable (/home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:208:32)
    at eachOfSeries (/home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:658:16)
    at awaitable (/home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:208:32)
    at /home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2947:9
    at awaitable (/home/runner/KnowledgeableFrequentStatistic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:208:32)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use `function(cb)` instead of `(cb)=>{}`. If you try console logging `this`, you will see that `this` is the function. This has to do with scoping. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp will give you some more info. Another place with some more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this